# run remote script for linux from windows with login in script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to know if i can somehow or someway run a remote linux script stored in windows machine through putty which can contain:

```
#!/bin/bash

su
<password>
<some operation which needs root permissions>
exit
<some operation with normal user credentials>
```

Since i tried above script but it does ask root password and then give error of not able to run commands and needed root access. I ran this script from putty using command line:

```
putty -ssh normaluser@linuxhost -pw <password> -t -m C:\myRootScript.sh
```

Thanks for answers
Ashutosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either login as the root user (not recommended!) or add the user that you're login in with to the sudoers file

```
sudo visudo
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

That will let you run sudo without a password.

Comment: ...Hey! That's what I was going to say! Get out of my head! (+1) :-P

Comment: Thanks, the other way i found is
putty -ssh <uname>@<host> -pw <passwd> -t -m C:\someLocalShell4Remote.sh
the contents of someLocalShell4Remote.sh file are
#!/bin/bash
su -c /home/<uname>/<remoteScript><<passwd
<passwd>
passwd

and <remoteScript> contains all necessary operation needed to be done by root...

Thanks a lot for ur answer mate, it helped too